# Java application : accessing database on a different computer

Tags: java, mysql, database, mysql-workbench, remote-server

I have an application that uses java se and while coding it I installed mysql workbench on localhost, everything works fine. Now I have to distribute the jar files so that people can use it. but when I try accessing the database it says connection error. In the database path I replaced localhost with the ip of the computer the database is on. Could someone please help me out.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Could you post the full error message???

Comment: you need to be able to ping or telnet the database server to make sure you can connect, have you tried to?

Comment: Check for database access permissions from remote hosts.

Comment: @Santosh Yeah i think thats the problem in the users window it says localhost ... how do i make it accessible from any ip?

Comment: @Qwe - excellent suggestion.  Koool - you should be able to "telnet YOUR-HOST 3306" to verify the MySql port is open between the client and the remote MySql server.

Comment: @paulsm4 Oh i cannot ping what am i supposed to do now?

Comment: @Qwe I cannot ping what should I do to fix it. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As you know, for JDBC in general, you need to specify the host in your connection string.
2. As you also know, you typically specify the driver in Class.forName(), and the driver's .jar directory in your Java CLASSPATH.
3. You're probably using the MySql/J connector - I believe that's all your client needs deployed along with your application.
4. You also need to make sure the mySql port (default 3306) is open.
5. Mysql "users" are defined and authorized on a per-host basis.  You'll also need to make sure this is set up correctly in your "Users" mysql table.
6. Be sure your application logs all available exception information.  Please post any specific error messages here.

'Hope that helps

PS:
The only relevance to "mysql workbench" is that your app happens to work when you run it locally, using mysql workbench, correct?  If so, it probably isn't a good tag for this question...

Comment: 1. check
2. Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
3. done
4. done

Answer (score 1):

Run the query on the DB as admin user.

```
GRANT ALL ON db1 TO 'jeffrey'@'%';
```

Assuming that `db1` is your schema and `jeffrey` is the user you want to give access to.

Comment: so if i have this code in my app

con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:mysql://ip/db1?"+"user=jeffrey&password=");

it should work right?

Comment: from above comments I tried to ping and it says request failed what would be a solution to that??

Comment: You mean you cannot ping the machine which has database ?